# "ERROR: [Errno 111] Connection refused" when i try to use nova image-list

Tags: openstack, openstack-nova

I am using debian 7 with openstack havana all in one node,keystone work perfectly,glace also work ,but after installing nova when i try

```
 # nova image-list
```

it responds

```
ERROR: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

i would really appreciate if someone can help me to find out the cause of this error .

Comment: nova --debug may help you track it down.  it's a very useful flag to know.  but be careful pasting output as it doesn't silence passwords or auth tokens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try,unsetting proxies

```
unset http_proxy 
unset https_proxy
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I got this problem because I'd blindly gone thru the config steps of a Debian/Wheezy install of Havana. I accidentally set the rabbitmq user name to something besides guest... when I was using the default name of guest for rabbitmq.

My solution was to

cd /etc; grep -r rabbit . | grep WRONG_NAME

and then fix the bad rabbit_user entries by putting in the right name. Then I had to restart all the daemons.

I did this on my compute node and on my controller. Things got a lot better after that.